# run a nested function on button click

Tags: javascript

I have a fetch API that fetches a response from the backend and I have a function inside the fetch that alerts the response. What I am trying to do is run the function on click of a button but the test function is not on the global scope so my button can't access it to run it. Is there any way I can run the function to alert the response on button click after getting the response? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:PORT/api/ROUTE`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((response) => {

    function test() {
      alert(response)
    }
  })
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: try to use javascript promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your current code, `test` is not even called by the `then` callback. Move that function into the global scope, but be aware that anyway if you click too soon, the response might not be available yet. So work with the promise:

```
let promise = fetch(`http://localhost:PORT/api/ROUTE`)
              .then(res => res.json());
test(); // Optional -- if you want to have the alert even when button is not clicked.

function test() {
   promise.then(response => alert(response));
}
```

If your purpose was to redo the fetch on every button click, then move all that logic inside `test`.

```
test(); // Optional -- when you want to initiate the fetch on page load

function test() {
   fetch(`http://localhost:PORT/api/ROUTE`)
       .then(res => res.json());
       .then(response => alert(response));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the alert after fetch completion:

```
function getdata() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:PORT/api/ROUTE`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((response) => {

        function test() {
          alert(response)
        }
      })
}

<button onclick="getdata()">CLICK ME</button>
```

getdata is called and fetch initiated. Upon fetch completion, test is called. Note that you can do multiple clicks and have fetches running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable in global scope, and assign a function to it upon fetching the data.

```js
var test;

fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/techysharnav/repos`)  //For Test purposes
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((response) => {
     test = (response)=>alert(response)
  })
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">CLICK ME</button>
```